# Error when trying to include multiple js sources: Check your javascripts.joinTo config

Tags: javascript, phoenix-framework, brunch

I'm trying to set up a basic app using `phoenix-elixir` and `brunch`, but am getting the following error:

> 23 Mar 10:18:10 - warn: node_modules/phoenix/priv/static/phoenix.js compiled, but not written. Check your javascripts.joinTo config
>   23 Mar 10:18:10 - warn: node_modules/phoenix_html/priv/static/phoenix_html.js compiled, but not written. Check your javascripts.joinTo config

This is what I have in `branch-config.js`:

```javascript
files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        "js/app.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/,
        "js/script.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/
      }
    }
    // ...
}
```

This is my folder structure:

```
web/
  static/
    js/
      app.js
      script.js
```

I do see `script.js` being included (I see it compiled into `priv/static/js` and also as a source in dev tools) but functions inside it don't exhibit the behaviour I'd expect them to do. They do work if I add the contents of `script.js` to `app.js`.

Interestingly `css` works fine if I do...

```javascript
stylesheets: {
  joinTo: "css/app.css",
  joinTo: "css/style.css"
},
```

If I format `js` similarly to `css`, there is no error, but, again, functions inside it won't kick in...

```javascript
javascripts: {
  joinTo: "js/app.js",
  joinTo: "js/script.js"
}
```

Do I need to add `script.js` to the `vendor` folder instead? Is `app.js` the only `js` script that can be used inside `web/js`? I feel I may be missing a setting somewhere.

**EDIT**:

> $ mix phoenix.new -v
>   Phoenix v1.1.4
>
> $ brunch -v
>   2.1.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your js files joined into one `app.js` file, just leave the config as the default

```
files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: {
        "js/app.js": /^(web\/static\/js)/
      }
    }
    // ...
}
```

This means all files in `web/static/js` will be concatenated into `app.js`. What's happening is basically you're telling brunch to join all javascripts into two different files which confuses it.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, though if I do that, I still get the same warning, and I also get an error in the browser console: `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "phoenix_html" from "web/static/js/app"`

Comment: do you have the whitelist in your brunch-config.js and `phoenix` and `phoenix_html` as dependencies in package.json?

Comment: I'm not sure about the whitelist, but I do have the dependencies... I tried something: I used `import script from "./script"` in `app.js` - apparently I still have to import it? does it matter what word I use after `import`? only asking as `script.js` contains an anonymous function, so I'm assuming the word `script` after `import` is just an arbitrary name, so I guess I could use anything...?

Comment: yes, you need to import it. brunch by default generates commonjs modules for all files so they won't run unless you use them somewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Needs to be updated for Phoenix 1.3, which no longer uses a web/static/js toplevel directory to store these.